# change the text "at" to "v" using css

Tags: css, wordpress, shortcode

Hi I Know little of coding but hoped the following is possible by using custom css

I am using a short code to insert a table into a wordpress page and I want the particular word **at** to be replaced by **v**   example Leopards at Lions  changes to Leopards v Lions

I have looked at the source code where the table appears and this looks like this

```
<table class='mstw-lm-table mstw-lm-schedules mstw-lm-table_catsleague' >
<thead><tr>
<th>Match Fixtures</th><th>Score</th><th>Round</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<td><div class='league-schedule-matchup'><div class='away-team-logo'></div>Leopards at Lions<div class='home-team-logo'></div></div></td><td> 5-23</td><td><a href='cats-league-201718/' target='_blank'>Round 1</a></td></tr><td><div class='league-schedule-matchup'><div class='away-team-logo'></div>Tigers at Pumas<div class='home-team-logo'></div></div></td><td> 37-7</td><td><a href='cats-league-201718/' target='_blank'>Round 1</a></td></tr><td><div class='league-schedule-matchup'><div class='away-team-logo'></div>Pumas at Lions<div class='home-team-logo'></div></div></td><td> 33-3</td><td><a href='cats-league-201718/' target='_blank'>Round 2</a></td></tr><td><div class='league-schedule-matchup'><div class='away-team-logo'></div>Tigers at Leopards<div class='home-team-logo'></div></div></td><td> 10-16</td><td><a href='cats-league-201718/' target='_blank'>Round 2</a></td></tr><td><div class='league-schedule-matchup'><div class='away-team-logo'></div>Leopards at Lions<div class='home-team-logo'></div></div></td><td>TBA</td><td><a href='cats-league-201718/' target='_blank'>Round 3</a></td></tr><td><div class='league-schedule-matchup'><div class='away-team-logo'></div>Pumas at Leopards<div class='home-team-logo'></div></div></td><td>TBA</td><td><a href='cats-league-201718/' target='_blank'>Round 3</a></td></tr><td><div class='league-schedule-matchup'><div class='away-team-logo'></div>Lions at Tigers<div class='home-team-logo'></div></div></td><td>TBA</td><td><a href='cats-league-201718/' target='_blank'>Round 4</a></td></tr><td><div class='league-schedule-matchup'><div class='away-team-logo'></div>Pumas at Leopards<div class='home-team-logo'></div></div></td><td>TBA</td><td><a href='cats-league-201718/' target='_blank'>Round 4</a></td></tr><td><div class='league-schedule-matchup'><div class='away-team-logo'></div>Lions at Tigers<div class='home-team-logo'></div></div></td><td>TBA</td><td><a href='cats-league-201718/' target='_blank'>Round 5</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

hope this makes sense and is possible and as I Said my limit will be adding custom css

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You have 9 unpaired closing `</tr>` tags..

Comment: The code is generated by a wordpress plugin and although as you say its invalid it does appear to work

Comment: It is working now but sometimes it will behave unexpectedly

Comment: You have to use JavaScript for that to replace `at` to 1v` using `replace('at', 'v')`

Comment: No way to achieve this using (only) CSS. Best to change text at its source (the database) or as close to the source as possible (e.g. with a custom WordPress filter - most probably hooked to `the_content`).

Comment: I think this is beyond me but was going to try to add Javascript to the particular page. I have found a sample and have added Rana suggested code but no idea if I have done this correctly function wpb_hook_javascript() {
  if (is_page ('202')) { 
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          // replace('at', 'v')
        </script>
    <?php
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');